# SQL query with variables

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am doing a PAT for school and I am doing the following how can I correct it. I want to send an entered **email address**, **name**, **Id
number**, **birth date**, **gender**, **town** and all is string my statement is:

```
Adoquery1.sql.text := 'insert into besprekings 
                       values('email', 'name', 'Id', 'birth', 'gender', 'town')';
```

The fields are as follows:

```
 Email(string), Name(string), ID(string), Birth(string), Gender(string), town(string)
```

This is not really homework it is a project that counts 25% of my years mark. I have finished everything but can't get this right. We have to bring in something new that we haven't learned in school and for me that is opening programs like mail(windows 8) and doing this I really apreciate everybody trying to help.

Comment: There is nothing like *urgent* on StackOverflow! But anyway, when you want to make `INSERT` query, then do it like `INSERT INTO (Column1, Column2) VALUES (Value1, Value2)`.

Comment: I tried it like that got error saying syntax error in insert into statement

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to use parameters in your query, and assign values to the parameters before calling ExecuteSQL. However, since you didn't provide us with any information about what data types you're using, it's pretty hard to help you do so. Also, no question on here is more important or urgent than any other. If you need immediate, urgent assistance, hire a contractor or consultant to do the work for you. StackOverflow is not a "please help me do my homework fast" site. :-) If you edit and post your DB schema (table definition) here, someone might be able to help you.

Comment: Like insert into tabel1(''column1'',''column2'',''column3'',ect) VALUES(''Value1'',''value2'',''value3'',ect)';

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean it like that I got this big project to do for school... All the values are string I said that I need to read 7 fields of data(string) into a tabel called besoekers

Comment: Can u please email me a sample just in txt form would do arnobotha001@hotmail.com

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't work like that, either. If answers are provided, they're posted here so everyone benefits from them; they're not mailed to you personally. Please take a few minutes to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn how things work here. Maybe you can do that while you're waiting for an answer. :-)

Comment: It sounds like you didn't do your homework, and you want us to do it for you :)

Comment: Please edit your question (with the `edit` link right under the `delphi` and `delphi-7` tags) and add the table information I asked for, which is the column name and column datatype for **each** column you need to update in your table. If you're not willing to give us the information, we can't help you.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use parameterized queries, to prevent SQL injection. Even though that might not be something to worry about in your app now, it's best to get in the habit of doing it right in the first place. I'll show a little of the code, and you can figure out how to finish it yourself.

First, properly populate your SQL. Specify the names of the columns you're inserting into, and the parameter names you'll be using to populate them (the parts starting with `:`):

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO beskprekings (email, name, Id)');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('VALUES (:email, :name, :Id)');
```

Now put the actual values to insert into the parameters, using the same names you used in your `VALUES` list:

```
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('email').Value := email;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('name').Value := name;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('id').Value := Id;
```

Now, execute the query.

The added benefit of doing it with parameterized queries is that, once it's been run once, you can simply repopulate the parameters and run it again; the database will already have done what it needs to to `prepare` the query (hint: the word I marked has meaning for ADO and other databases - you should look into it) so that it's much faster when you use it again and again.

Comment: Thanks I will be sure to try it like that this afternoon and will post my results here

Comment: "Don't forget to close it afterwards"  You don't have to close an INSERT query.  Execute it with EXECSQL, not OPEN....

Comment: @user582118: Of course. Forgot this was ADO. The DB I use most allows `Open` for `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `CREATE` statements and doesn't require the separate `ExecSQL`, so I'm in the habit of closing them. Will correct. Thanks for the catch. :-)

Comment: I tried it like you said and got a error saying that AsString is a undeclared identifier and that there is a problem with the insert into statement

Comment: You know, you **really** need to start trying to things things through yourself. If you remove the `AsString` and then put the text cursor right after the `.`, Delphi will **tell** you what's available to choose to put there. `Value` is the obvious choice. As far as "problem with the insert statement", it looks fine, and you've not given **any** information about what the roblem is - just saying "there's a problem" doesn't help when we're not sitting in front of your screen to see what the problem is, and you don't post the error message.

Comment: I did try the .value it also gives a error I aint at my computer now wil post the correct problem at 9:10 pm tonight central africa time

Comment: I just tested this code. I used `create table beskprekings([email] varchar(50), [name] varchar(25), [id] varchar(5));` in SQL Server Mgmt Studio to create the table, and used the variables `EMail, aName, ID: string;` in a new Delphi app with a button and an ADOQuery. I built a connection string for the ADOQuery in the Object Inspector, and assigned values to those three variables in a button click event, used the **identical code** from the parameter assignments above (changing the `:= name;` one to `:= aName;` to match the variables I used), and added `ADOQuery1.ExecSQL` as the final line.

Comment: -continued- I then ran the app and clicked the button, then closed the app. I went back into SQL Server Mgmt Studio and did a `select * from beskprekings`, and saw the row I just added from my code in the results. If it's not working for you, you're doing something wrong.