# Delphi 10.1 FireDac and Sqlite date issue

Tags: android, sqlite, date, delphi, where-clause

I have a table that is created in my android app.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TimeSheet  
  `TKey` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `PriKey1` INT NOT NULL,
  `PriKey2` DEFAULT NULL,
  `PriKey3` DEFAULT NULL,
  `STime` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `ETime` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `Note` BLOB);
```

I have loaded some data using various dates.

And I need to filter so as only one days data is shown at a time.

Delphi code to do so is below

```
FD := "a date";
QuTimeSheet.Active := False;
QuTimeSheet.SQL.Text := 'Select Date(STime) as SDate, Time(STime) as STime,     Time(ETime) as ETime, Task.TaskName From TimeSheet' + #13 + #10 +
'  LEFT JOIN task ON (TimeSheet.PriKey1 = task.TKey)';// + #13 + #10 +
'Where SDate = ''' + formatdatetime('YYYY-MM-DD',FD) + ''';';
QuTimeSheet.Active := True;
```

If I remove the where statement SDate has some DD-MM-1800 date. Which tells me that the Date(STime) dosent work in Delphi.

Have also tried strfTime(%Y-&M-%D, STime) as SDate

Delphi dosent seem to like strfTime android device crashes.

Have tried using a filter

```
  QuTimeSheet.Filtered := False;
  QuTimeSheet.Filter := 'SDate = ''' + formatdatetime('YYYY-MM-DD',FD) + '''';
  QuTimeSheet.Filtered := True;
```

or

```
  QuTimeSheet.Filtered := False;
  QuTimeSheet.Filter := 'SDate = ''' + Datetostr(FD) + '''';
  QuTimeSheet.Filtered := True;
```

This filters nothing.

This is such a simple where statement that works in MySql and on the Sqlite turorials site.

Why not in my app.

Comment: Stop concatenating your SQL. Use parameterized queries instead. Let the DB driver worry about properly formatting parameter values, remove the `Date()` from the SQL, and get the basic query working properly with parameters first. There are multiple examples here about using parameters with Delphi. Stop with the `formatdatetime` and all of that, and simply use the parameter.

Comment: Should have included this: See TFDQuery.ParamByName, and use it with FDQuery1.ParamByName('SDate').AsDateTime instead of formatting to a string. While it's not for FireDAC, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11834743/62576) should give you the general idea.

Comment: You cant pass a DateTime Variable (FD) into a text script without tuning it into a string. Whats concatenating and parameterized mean. I need to ignore the time aspect of the values so I need to format the values I would have thougnt

Comment: Yes, you can, using parameters. I just gave you the code to do so. See my last comment, which gives you an example of doing precisely that without any conversion. The database driver takes the value passed using `AsDateTime` and converts it to the proper date format for the database. Concatenating means *using + and quotes to build your SQL*, and the linked post I gave you shows how to use parameters. Did you look at the linked answer at all?

Answer (score 3):

Stop concatenating your SQL, and use parameters instead. Also, stop converting things from one type to another yourself, and let the database driver do it for you; it knows how to quote things that need to be quoted (and not quote those that don't), and how to properly format date values. It also prevents SQL injection.

Something like this should work (untested, because I don't have SQLite on this machine):

```
var
  TheDate: TDateTime;
begin
  TheDate := EncodeDate(2015, 1, 1);
  QuTimeSheet.Active := False;
  QuTimeSheet.SQL.Text := 'Select Date(STime) as SDate, Time(STime) as STime,'#13 +
                        ' Time(ETime) as ETime, Task.TaskName From TimeSheet'#13 +
                        ' LEFT JOIN task ON (TimeSheet.PriKey1 = task.TKey)'#13 +
                        'Where SDate = :SDateVal';
  QuTimeSheet.ParamByName('SDateVal').AsDateTime := TheDate;
  QuTimeSheet.Active := True;
end;
```

Comment: OK so I have tried all sorts of combinations. I like your suggestion I see all sorts of benefits doing it this way. Ok so I can have the app compile now and it dosnt lock up. However It dosnt display any data. I have been playing around in the IDE and executing the commands. Have found that if I remove the where statement I have data for the specific data that have been loading time ie STime is filled with '2016-07-31 12:00 AM' however the SDate column is empty.

Comment: My understanding is it should have '2016-07-31' in it. This is I believe why the where statement dosnt work. Can you surgest a work around obviusly I have multiple times I need to show for that date thats why Im trying to remove the time form the field for the filter.

Comment: As I've explained (more than once), using AsDateTime will automatically set it to the proper format, so you don't have to do so. I can't suggest a work around (other than what I've already written) because I don't have your specific data.

Comment: Thanks for your Help Ken but I have copied your code and dont have the result I want. to Quote you(untested, because I don't have SQLite on this machine): I Have SqLite running in my Delphi enviroment and even primary issue at the moment is Date(TDateTime) in Sqlite does not work.

Comment: if I only have Select Date(STime) as SDate, Time(STime) as STime,                Time(ETime) as ETime, Task.TaskName From TimeSheet as my script the SDate colunm has no data in it so the where is not going to work. I think the

Comment: I just got to a machine where I can test. I can sucessfully open the SQLite Demo database on Berlin, open the FireDAC Explorer SQL window, and run the query `SELECT OrderID, Date(OrderDate) FROM Orders LIMIT 10;`, where I see the proper data. This indicates that `Date()` works just fine in FireDAC, which means it works just fine in Delphi code, which means the problem is in your data. As I said, I don't have access to your data from here. I've shown you the proper way to use SQL in Delphi, and the proper way to set DateTime parameters. I don't know what else I can do for you here.

Comment: Solved the issue where SDate = Date(:FilterDate)